# SQL Server Named Instance port configured with 1434, Will that create any issues in future?

Tags: sql-server

While completing configuration for a named instance in a failover Cluster, I had used 1434 for configuring the TCP/IP which is actually default port for SQL browser.

Now the project is already started and is live for a while and many app servers are configured to connect to the Instance.  In the config file, developers are using *Instance name,1434* and getting connected to DB.

My Doubt is ,  whether there is any scenario which can create problems by continuing like that, or is it must that I have to change the port number?

Comment: It's not a "must", but I would suggest that you consider it. Technically speaking, you could (foolishly) run the instance on almost any port, like 80 (normally for http), or 22 (normally for SSH), but that doesn't mean you *should*, and you could easily confuse users/administrators that aren't used to the "odd"/conflicting choice of port number for the service.

Comment: The default port for the SQL Browser Service is udp/1434. You have configured SQL Server on tcp/1434 which is a different port because it's a different IP protocol. It's not going to cause technical issues but, as you've already discovered, it's going to cause wetware issues as people get confused by it.

Comment: I AM  THANKFUL TO  EACH ONE OF YOU FOR YOUR VALUABLE COMMENTS. Actually speaking There are lot of Applications configured in multiple app servers using the dbs in that instance. So any changes made should involve approval from multiple Application owners to reconfigure with new port. And also it goes for top management approval as well. Hence Technically, if this configuration wont encounter any issue, then I would think of not to  disturb the same.  Thats why I thought of getting suggestions from Sql Server Doctors  in Stackoverflow.......